# Keep spinner position when screen orientation is changed

Tags: android, spinner

I want to keep the spinner position when the screen is rotated

I've looked at a few answers on here and so far have the following

Aim - Store the position of the spinner

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    flav1Spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Combo_InvChoice1);
    Integer flav1 = flav1Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    savedInstanceState.putInt("cho1", flav1);
}
```

Aim - Restore position

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculation);
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
   if (savedInstanceState != null){
        flav1Spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Combo_InvChoice1);
        Integer flav1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("cho1");
        flav1Spinner.setSelection(flav1);
    }
```

However while debugging I can see that the Integer Flav1 is getting a value assigned to it and the digit is being retrieved, however the spinner isn't changing it's position. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have an adapter for the spinner ?

Comment: You should setAdapter() before setSelection().

Comment: @Blackbelt there is one at some point, as the spinner is getting populated from values in a database

Comment: you might want to call `setSelection` after `setAdapter`

Comment: thanks both, but what would i set the adapter too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `onSaveInstanceState()`, As below

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("yourSpinner", yourSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    // do this for each of your Spinner

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        yourSpinner.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("yourSpinner", 0));
        // do this for every text views
    }
}
```

Check [Saving Activity state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android), it will help you to get more details.